# Print Unicode Character in Console

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode

I have written the following code to represent a Unicode-based character at console output of windows but when I run the code, VS shows me an error with the following information:

```
Debug Assertation Failed

Expression: buffer_size % 2 == 0
```

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

auto main() -> decltype(0) {
    bool status = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    if (status == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Everything is working fine." << std::endl;
    }

    wchar_t Message[] = L"\x263a";
    std::cout << Message << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you should use `std::wcout` as: _"Unicode mode is for wide print functions (for example, wprintf) and is not supported for narrow print functions. Use of a narrow print function on a Unicode mode stream triggers an assert."_ see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2019

Comment: @RichardCritten You should post this as answer.